# WSDL Operations not being updated

Tags: ruby, curl, wsdl, savon

I'm a bit stumped as to why our new operations are not being picked up when using the Savon gem but are when using a simple curl command.

For example when using Savon

```
@client = Savon.client(wsdl: "#url-here", basic_auth: %w(username password))
@client.operations
:operation_name
# At this point i expect the operation to be OperationName
```

When I then run a curl request

```
curl #url-here --user username:password
```

Within the XML response is

```
<operation name="OperationName">
```

We recently changed the naming convention of our operations to camel case (previously using snake case) so the tests used to pass but now they fail as not picking up the new operations (When using Savon)

Would there be any reason for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1 of Savon:

> Your service probably uses (lower)CamelCase names for actions and params, but Savon maps those to snake_case Symbols for you.

I assume, Savon mapped your new camel case actions to snake case. So if you had updated your tests - you shouldn't.